# Entity framework using old primary keys when inserting new records in database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I have a run into a serious problem several times now using MVC 4 and EF.
The problem is best illustrated by example:

I have records in a DB table with the following PKs, 1,2,3,4.
1 and 2 are deleted. When EF goes to insert a new record, it is assigning it with PK 1 again. The next insert will use 2 and then it will try 3 and get a PK violation.

I saw the same thing yesterday in another table with another insert.

In the following, image you can see that the db.SaveChanges failed when inserting the a new record with PK 3.

[image]

As you can see the DB is set to auto-increment from the following image:

[image]

Here is my controller action (it is used for inserts and edits - but that should not matter):

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //update pricelist
            Pricelist pricelist = new Pricelist();            
            pricelist.InjectFrom(adminEditPricelistVM.Pricelist);
            pricelist.PricelistProducts = new List<PricelistProduct>();

            pricelist.SubscriberId = (int)UserManagement.getUsersSubscriberId(WebSecurity.GetUserId(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));

            if (adminEditPricelistVM.Pricelist.PricelistId != 0)
            {
                db.Entry(pricelist).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Pricelists.Add(pricelist);

            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            adminEditPricelistVM.Pricelist.PricelistId = pricelist.PricelistId;

 etc...
```

The only clue I have is that in the seeding config for my data, we are using the following commands to begin the seeding at 1, when replacing the data:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Features',  RESEED, 1)");
```

Perhaps this has something to do with it, but I doubt it - since this is not called at that time.

BTW, this is not consistent. I cannot replicate manually. It just seems to happen from time-to-time and when it does, EF will continue to err on each insert attempt until it passes all the used IDs and finds the next free one. In other words, I will get an error inserting on PK 3. Then on the next insert attempt, it will err on PK 4 and then on the next attempt it will succeed because PK 5 was not being used. It's as if, there is a memory of PKs in use somewhere that gets reset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I can confirm that the problem is caused by the DB reseed. This basically sets the count back to 1 regardless of any remaining records in the DB. Weird but true.